# ionViewDidEnter method is not fired when pressed back button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

**discover.html(Ionic page)**

```
 <p>MY TOPICS</p>
      <div class="cardScroll">
        <ng-template ngFor let-topic [ngForOf]="topicdata">
          <topic [data]="topic"></topic>
        </ng-template>
 </div>
```

**discover.ts**

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-discover',
  templateUrl: 'discover.html',
})
export class Discover {

  constructor() {
  }

  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.GetData();
  }
}
```

**topic.html**

```
   <ion-card (click)="getTopicPage()">

    </ion-card>
```

**topic.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, App } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    selector: 'topic',
    templateUrl: 'topic.html'
})
export class Topic {
    @Input() data;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public appCtrl: App) {
    }


    getTopicPage() {
        this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push('TopicPage', { data: this.data });
    }

}
```

**topic-page.html**

```
<ion-content>
 <button ion-button clear (click)='goToBack()'><ion-icon name="arrow-back">
 </ion-icon></button>
</ion-content>
```

**topic-page.ts**

```
@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-topic-page',
    templateUrl: 'topic-page.html',
})
export class TopicPage {

    goToBack(): void {
       this.navCtrl.pop();
     }
}
```

Hope you can see the flow of the components above.The parent page is `discover`.The problem here is when I pressed the `topic-page` back button where it never fires the `discover` page's  `ionViewDidEnter()` method.Can you tell me how to do that?

**Note:** When I pressed the back button it comes to `discover` page.But it never fires the `ionViewDidEnter()` method.

Comment: maybe its because your navigating from `rootNav`? Using injected Navcontroller didnt work?

Comment: Why do you use `this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push()`. Why not `this.navCtrl.push()`

Comment: @Duannx I have put a new question for that too.Please see that.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822363/differences-between-getrootnav-and-navctrl-methods

Comment: @suraj I have put a new question for that too.Please see that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44822363/differences-between-getrootnav-and-navctrl-methods

Comment: hi..did you find solution ?? I am also facing same issue