# Differences between getRootNav() and navCtrl() methods

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Can you tell me what are the differences of below 2 methods? Which moment should I use it?

*book.ts*

```
this.app.getRootNav().push('FromBook', { bookId: this.data.id })

this.navCtrl.push('FromBook', { bookId: this.data.id });
```

When we use inner components like below sometimes it works.Sometimes it is not.Why this kind of different behavior with above 2 navigation methods?

*author-page.html*

```
<div>
        <book *ngFor="let book of authorData?.books" [data]="book"></book>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both methods add a new page to the current Nav component, the only difference is to **which Nav Controller**.

If your app is a Tabs page, with several tabs, each tab has its own Nav component. That's why if you try to push a page from inside of a child tab by doing `this.navCtrl.push(ThePage)` that new page won't be shown if you switch to another tab, but if you come back to the previous tab, that page will still be visible. That's because the page was pushed to a child Nav component, the Nav component from the single tab.

If you use `this.app.getRootNav().push(ThePage)`, your pushing the new page to the Nav component of the root app, so it doesn't matter if the component where you are doing that has its own Nav component, the Nav from the Root component will be used.

The tab was just an example, the same is valid when you try to push a page from any **overlay component (popover, modal, alert, etc)**

This is included in [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-an-overlay-component):

> Navigating from an Overlay Component
>
> What if you wanted to navigate from an overlay component (popover,
>   modal, alert, etc)? In this example, we've displayed a popover in our
>   app. From the popover, we'll get a reference of the root NavController
>   in our app, using the getRootNav() method.
>
> ```
> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
> import { App, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
>
> @Component({
>     template: `
>     <ion-content>
>       <h1>My PopoverPage</h1>
>       <button ion-button (click)="pushPage()">Call pushPage</button>
>      </ion-content>
>     `
>   })
>   class PopoverPage {
>     constructor(
>       public viewCtrl: ViewController
>       public appCtrl: App
>     ) {}
>
>     pushPage() {
>       this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
>       this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push(SecondPage);
>     }
>   }
> ```

Comment: Great explanation.Thanks.One question though.Can't we use `this.navCtrl.push()` within overlay component?

Comment: Hope you have a feedback for above comment?

Comment: Ups, sorry, I didn't see the SO notification. You could use `this.navCtrl.push()` within a child tab, but if you want to push a page from within an alert or a popover, you definitely should use `this.app.getRootNav().push()` to avoid errors/bugs. Otherwise it might look like it works properly, but maybe behind the scenes the NavController has an inconsistent state...

Comment: Thank you very much.I really appreciate your clear explanation.Have a nice day ahead :)

Comment: Np, I'm so happy to hear that :)